# SQL Server LockMatchID Command

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, audit

I am seeing calls like those shown below in my SQL Server Audit logs but have no idea what it means. A google search turned up a possible relationship with compiles/recompiles. The line (or similar lines) can also be found inside several SQL Server internal sprocs.

```
  EXEC %%Object(MultiName = @objname).LockMatchID(ID = @objid, Exclusive = 1, BindInternal = 0)
```

Does anyone have an understanding of this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an internal method, presumably - from the name - used to lock an object based on its `object_id` and ensure that the executing user has the rights to make further changes to the object. This locking is required to do things like adding/dropping properties, hidden columns, etc., and to ensure that the object can't be dropped or altered by others in the meantime (mere mortals tend to do this by starting a transaction and locking the table through some indirect method, since there is no `LOCK TABLE` command - but clearly there is internal plumbing to help with system operations).

If you look at any of the procedures where this is used (there is a large list):

```
SELECT N'EXEC sp_helptext ''sys.' + QUOTENAME(name) + N''';' 
FROM sys.all_objects 
WHERE [schema_id] = 4
  AND LOWER(OBJECT_DEFINITION([object_id])) LIKE N'%lockmatchid%';
```

You'll see preceding comments like:

```
-- Lock the table schema and check permissions

-- Share lock default so it cannot be dropped

-- Since binding a default is a schema change, update schema count
--  for the object in the sysobjects table.

-- Ex-lock and check permission

-- Share Lock rule so that it cannot be dropped

-- Check that table and column exist

-- RESOLVE OBJECT NAME

-- Get exclusive object lock upfront so subsequent %%ColumnEx can proceed

-- Acquire sch-M lock up-front on the published object 

-- LOCK PROC & CHECK PERMISSION --

-- LOCK, CHECK PERMISSION, BUMP SCHEMA FOR RECOMPILE  --

-- obtain owner-qual object name

-- Re-acquire schema mod lock to make the code more resilient to changes
-- although this must have been done inside sp_Mrepl_schema

-- LOCK TABLE, CHECK STANDARD TABLE-DDL PERMISSIONS

-- Since binding a default is a schema change,
--  update schema count for the object in the sysobjects table.

-- Update schema count for the object in the sysobjects table.

-- Verify that table exists
```

(And people say commenting code is a waste of time.)

*There also seems to be `LockExclusiveMatchID` method, though the `Exclusive` argument seems to have later been added to `LockMatchID`, which made the exclusive method obsolete.*

Not sure how much more specific you need to this to be - if you want to track down where this a high occurrence of these, you need to look at the outer calls, not this specific statement. For example, do you have an application that is renaming objects a lot, or calling `sp_autostats` directly, changing replication, or anything else you can infer from the list generated above? You'll have to figure out which procedures are getting called to help determine the *why*. And what you'll do about it (if you can even determine that there is a "problem") won't have anything to do with `LockMatchID` specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I saw a lot of locks generated by same statements and deadlocks happened on server during the same 3 minutes.

Via deadlock reports I figured out that deadlocks happened with my processes and this system process in my case:
Proc [Database Id = 32767 Object Id = -993696157]

```
select DB_NAME(32767)--NULL
select OBJECT_NAME(-993696157)--sp_MSactivate_auto_sub
```

According to [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/a06e8e51-8c4b-4288-ae56-8e4ef42524fa/blocked-process-report-blocking-lock-type?forum=sqldatabaseengine) it is related to replication system task.

This is a typical callstack from blocked-process-report\blocking-process\process\executionStack in my case:

```
      <executionStack>
        <frame line="30" stmtstart="1570" stmtend="1796" sqlhandle="0x0300ff7f66f82acdcaae2d0054a9000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" />
        <frame line="917" stmtstart="67266" stmtend="67522" sqlhandle="0x0300ff7f48dddfc2a8b02d0054a9000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" />
        <frame line="52" stmtstart="3496" stmtend="5162" sqlhandle="0x0300ff7f5eea5ef7d25b2d0054a9000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" />
        <frame line="92" stmtstart="4236" stmtend="4768" sqlhandle="0x0300ff7f6366c5c416b12d0054a9000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" />
      </executionStack>
```

If I decode it with this query:

```
select
cast(
             (select SUBSTRING(txt.text,(ISNULL(T.x.value('./@stmtstart', 'int'), 0) / 2) + 1,
                           ((CASE ISNULL(T.x.value('./@stmtend', 'int'), -1)
                                  WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(txt.text)
                                  ELSE T.x.value('./@stmtend', 'int')
                              END - ISNULL(T.x.value('./@stmtstart', 'int'), 0)) / 2) + 1) + CHAR(13) AS statement_txt
                              ,T.x.value('./@line', 'int') as line
                       from @bpReportXml.nodes('//blocking-process/process/executionStack/frame') AS T(x)
                       cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(T.x.value('xs:hexBinary(substring((./@sqlhandle), 3))', 'varbinary(max)')) AS txt
                       for XML path('')) as xml) AS frame_blocking_process_xml
```

Then I get this result:

```
<statement_txt>EXEC %%Object(MultiName = @qualified_name).LockMatchID(ID = @object_id, Exclusive = 1, BindInternal = 0)

</statement_txt>
<line>30</line>
<statement_txt>exec sys.sp_MSsetfilteredstatus @tabid

                    -- clear nonsqlsub status for this article.


</statement_txt>
<line>917</line>
<statement_txt>EXEC @retcode = @cmd
                    @publication,
                    @article,
                    @subscriber,
                    @status,
                    @previous_status,
                    @destination_db,
                    @frequency_type,
                    @frequency_interval,
                    @frequency_relative_interval,
                    @frequency_recurrence_factor,
                    @frequency_subday,
                    @frequency_subday_interval,
                    @active_start_time_of_day,
                    @active_end_time_of_day,
                    @active_start_date,
                    @active_end_date,
                    @optional_command_line,
                    @distribution_jobid OUTPUT,
                    @from_auto_sync,
                    @ignore_distributor,
                    -- Agent offload
                    @offloadagent,
                    @offloadserver,
                    @dts_package_name,
                    @dts_package_password,
                    @dts_package_location,
                    @skipobjectactivation,
                    @distribution_job_name,
                    @publisher,
                    @publisher_type
                    ,@ignore_distributor_failure


</statement_txt>
<line>52</line>
<statement_txt>EXECUTE @retcode =   sys.sp_changesubstatus 
                        @publication = @publication,
                        @article = @article,
                        @status = @status,
                        @from_auto_sync = @from_auto_sync,
                        @skipobjectactivation = @skipobjectactivation,
                        @publisher = @publisher


</statement_txt>
<line>92</line>
```